# Postgresql 13: Blocked queries

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

I have a database server running Postgresql 13.4 in AWS RDS. I'm trying to use pglogical to replicate in our data from our 9.6 Postgres RDS instance. Pglogical status is currently 'down' and I'm trying to get an understanding of how much data has replicated in and how much is left to go.

Problem is, on some of our larger tables, the queries are not completing.

Sample query: `select * from my_table limit 1`

And the goal of this is just to see one row in the table to see if the table is empty or not. The query is currently running for 45 minutes and not completing.

I believe the query is not blocked by a pg lock, because: `select * from pg_locks where not granted;` has no results.

in `pg_stat_activity` I can see that the query has been in `active` state for the entire time. I am running an `analyze` query on a different table, but not on `my_table`.

What could be blocking this query?

Comment: What do the other columns of pg_stat_activity show?  In particular, wait_event.

Comment: You probably have a huge table full of uncommitted or aborted data, which has to be laboriously inspected then ignored (or cleaned up).

Comment: @jjanes the state is active and wait_event and wait_event_type are both null. Is there anyway to get some idea of how much uncommitted/aborted data there is?

Comment: Seeing that is not easy.  You could use the heap_page_items from pageinspect extension (but you need to be the superuser)